# Pivoting data for stacked charts (grouping and creating new columns for each distinct value)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, aggregate, pivot, group-by

I have something that looks like this ([SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d420/1)):

```
Date        Location    Value
1/1/2012    Baltimore   36
1/1/2012    Houston     36
1/1/2012    Chicago     55
2/1/2012    Baltimore   49
2/1/2012    Houston     58
2/1/2012    Chicago     51
3/1/2012    Baltimore   11
3/1/2012    Houston     13
3/1/2012    Chicago     18
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
Date        Baltimore   Houston     Chicago
1/1/2012    36          36          55
2/1/2012    49          58          51
3/1/2012    11          13          18
```

How do I group by the `Date` and create new columns for each distinct `Location`? I do not know the complete set of possible `Location`s. I'm working in Oracle 11g Release 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this if the columns are known is using an aggregate and a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT d,
  sum(case when loc = 'Baltimore' then v else 0 end) as Baltimore,
  sum(case when loc = 'Houston' then v else 0 end) as Houston,
  sum(case when loc = 'Chicago' then v else 0 end) as Chicago
FROM test
group by d
order by d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25850/4)

If you want to do this dynamically, then you can create a procedure to generate the SQL statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select d ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct loc from test order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , sum(case when loc = '''||x.loc||''' then v end) as '||x.loc;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from test group by d order by 1';

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then to call it:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x
```

the result is:

```
D                                BALTIMORE    CHICAGO    HOUSTON
------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
01-JAN-12 12.00.00.000000 AM            36         55         36
01-FEB-12 12.00.00.000000 AM            49         51         58
01-MAR-12 12.00.00.000000 AM            11         18         13
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a normal `PIVOT` operation (in Oracle 11g R2), you need to know the locations:

```
with foo as
(
  select d,loc,v
  from test
)
select *
from foo
pivot (
sum(v)
  for loc in ('Baltimore','Houston','Chicago')
)
order by 1;
```

If you don't know all locations there are hacky ways of doing it, but they're not pretty. [This Oracle forum thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3227306) has (hacky) examples that can be used when the columns aren't known.